# Make for statements on same line but not next input

Tags: python, output

So I have a slight problem with the code I am working on.

```
while True:    
    r = input("Line: ")
    n = r.split()
    if r == " ":
        break  
    else:
      for word in n:
        print(word[::-1]),
```

It is designed to output the reverse of each word of the input, and to repeat the process until a blank is entered. However, I tried using `print (end=" ")` but it would make the input on the same line as well like this:

```
Line: hello world
olleh dlrow Line:
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I want it to output this:

```
olleh dlrow
Line:
```

Comment: What is wrong? What is the expected output for some example inputs?

Comment: It was supposed to be olleh world and Line: on the next line

Comment: Add a `print('\n')` at the end of the while loop.

Comment: Or you could do `r = input("\nLine: ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print an empty line after the `for` loop, like so:

```
print
```

(i.e. the `print` keyword with nothing after it.)